# wpf DataGrid Scroll with mouseclick scrollBar Error when Row Drag and Drop

Tags: wpf, datagrid, drag

I wrote DoDragDrop in DataGrid.

However, i can't click and drag scroll bar on DataGrid because Drag Error occurred.

But i can scroll with mouse wheel.

How can I fix it?   Here is a part of my code.

**.cs file**

```
private void datagrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(incidentList);
            object selectedItem = datagrid.SelectedItem;
            if (selectedItem != null)
            {
                DataGridRow container = (DataGridRow)datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedItem);
                var dataObj = new DataObject();
                dataObj.SetData("DragSource", container);
                if (container != null)
                {

                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(container, dataObj, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

**.xaml file**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyColumnHeader}" 
              Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}" CanUserAddRows="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="150" SelectionMode="Single"
              ItemsSource="{Binding myListData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"            
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectMyRow}" 
              MouseMove="datagrid_MouseMove"> .....
```

Comment: Maybe you should verify the mouse position to be within the boundaries of your `container` or even better, register the mousemove on `DataGridRow` instead of `DataGrid` so you can painlessly start the drag on the actually dragged row instead of dragging the selected item and interferring with the scrollbar ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register your handler on the row instead of the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="RowMoveHandler"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

And then take the sender-row as container:

```
private void RowMoveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var container = sender as DataGridRow;
    if (container != null && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        var dataObj = new DataObject();
        dataObj.SetData("DragSource", container);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(container,
                    dataObj,
                    DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow really thanks. It works and I can use scrollBar with mouse! But when I try to start drag a row, selectedRow is changing while dragging. Why is it change?

Comment: @parfum Well probably because `RowMoveHandler` is not checking for a currently active drag operation before starting a new drag when moving over a different row.

Comment: Edit: thats probably not it... you have to give more details about your code to get an answer to that.